Evaluating $\int_0^1\cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=1}^{2023}x_k\left\{\frac1{x_k}\right\}dx_1\cdots dx_{2023}$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$
Recently came across this  integral;

$$I=\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=1}^{2023}  x_k
 \left\{\frac{1}{x_k}\right\} dx_1 \cdots dx_{2023}$$ $\{x\}$ represents the fractional part of $x$.

Here's the steps to my approach,
$$I=\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=2}^{2023}  x_k \left\{\frac{1}{x_k}\right\} \left(\int_0^1 x_1 \left\{\frac{1}{x_1}\right\} dx_1\right)dx_2 \cdots dx_{2023}$$
Substituting $x_1=\frac{1}{t}$ and $dx_1=\frac{-dt}{t^2}$
$$I=\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=2}^{2023}  x_k \left\{\frac{1}{x_k}\right\} \left(\int_{1}^{{\infty}} \frac{1}{t} \left\{t\right\} \frac{dt}{t^2}\right)dx_2 \cdots dx_{2023}$$
$$I=\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=2}^{2023}  x_k \left\{\frac{1}{x_k}\right\} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{t-k}{t^3}dt\right)dx_2 \cdots dx_{2023}$$
$$I=\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=2}^{2023}  x_k \left\{\frac{1}{x_k}\right\} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}-\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)dx_2 \cdots dx_{2023}$$
$$I=\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=2}^{2023}  x_k \left\{\frac{1}{x_k}\right\} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(k+1)}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} -\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)dx_2 \cdots dx_{2023}$$
By telescoping and using $\zeta(2)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$;
$$I=\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{k=2}^{2023}  x_k \left\{\frac{1}{x_k}\right\} \left(1-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2} \right)dx_2 \cdots dx_{2023}$$
In similar manner the remaining integrals can be evaluated to give the final result;

$$I=\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12} \right)^{2023}$$

I have recently started to learn more ways to solve and view an integral to learn new concepts. I would like to see more ways of evaluating this interesting integral, moreover is the solution correct?

If all integrals are separable, what is the point to make it a multivariable-integral instead of a single variable integral?

@MathFail I did not give much thought about the design of this question, how do you intend to redesign this question?

I would like to compute just a single variable integral, as the one you demonstrate.

@MathFail you mean $I= \left(\int_0^1 x
\left{\frac{1}{x}\right} , dx \right)^{2023}$
